# Trying to understand the Choice type in F#

Tags: generics, f#, discriminated-union

I've been struggling to understand the code in the RoP article by Scott Wlaschin:

http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/railway-oriented-programming-carbonated/

He makes use of the Choice1Of2 & Choice2Of2 types in F#.  I was trying to come to terms with how to utilize these things by debugging them, when I came across the the following scenario:

```ml
module TestModule
open Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

// generic union type (like Choice1Of2, I think)
type Things<'a> =
    | Thing of 'a

// explicit union type (for comparison)
type Numbers =   
    | Integer of int

[<TestClass>]
type Tests() =

    // method to make a Choice1Of2 (from the article)
    let makeChoice (a : string) : Choice<string, 'a> = 
        Choice1Of2 a

    [<TestMethod>]
    member public this.WhyYouNoHaveItemValueAndStuff() =      
        let choice1 = Thing "test"          // debug = Thing "this"
        let choice2 = Integer 3             // debug = Integer 3
        let choice3 = makeChoice "test"     // debug = Choice1Of2 w/Item = "test"
        let choice4 = Choice1Of2 "test"     // debug = Tests.choice4@24 ???

        // bogus test stuff below here
        let choices = (choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4)
        Assert.IsNotNull(choices)
```

Why is it that when I make a Choice1Of2 directly (choice4), do I not get the same debugging result as choice 3.  Why is using a method to make choice3 neccessary to get the same kind of result as choice1 & 2?

**EDIT:**

It seems that changing choice4 to this:

```
let choice4 : Choice<string, Object> = Choice1Of2 "test"
```

works it out.  It's just totally unclear to me why I need that there.  The right side of the assignment is as clear as day to what type is being set.

Comment: Not sure what exactly type inference is doing there, but it's probably confused by the undefined type of these values. The run-time type is `Choice<string, obj>` for both, and they seem identical in usage. With a type annotation like `: Choice<string, int>` on `choice3` and `choice4`, they also look identical in debug information.

Comment: @Vandroiy Thx for the response.  That does indeed force the correct behavior.  Still strange that it's necessary.

Comment: It seems to me that this isn't really about correct behavior, it's about what you observe in the debugger. My guess is that what you're seeing is that choice4 has an incompletely inferred type, and that the internal representation of an incompletely inferred type is different from that of a type with a generic parameter. Unless you can find a case where those bindings are evaluated or typecheck differently in code (as opposed to in the debugger), I don't think this amounts to anything more than a VS implementation detail.

Comment: @NateC-K Fair enough.  I image you are probably right and that's just the way it is.  I'm still learning f#, I just assumed there was something I didn't know.  Thanks

Comment: Late response, I came across the F# Choice, then I realized it is the same as the type Either from Scala/Haskell: Here is the doc for scala: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html. If you search for `either` functional programming you should find a lot of information. It is ubiquitous. I kind of like better `Either` because it forces you think Right is always the successful path and Left is the error branch. However, Choice is more abstract.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The definition of the Choice type is as follows

```
 type Choice<'a, 'b> =
      | Choice1Of2 of 'a
      | Choice2Of2 of 'b
```

So when you construct an instance of the Choice type as you do in `choice4` you only use one of these legs, this essentially leaves a hole (the type describing `'b`) that the debugger has to fill, in fact at runtime it can't even be sure that the type is actually `Choice<'a,'b>` so you'll get some temporary type that is represented by an FSharpFunc. In much the same way the type inference mechanism would report `Choice<string, 'a>` where `'a` represents the hole, until the instance is matched over which would then force you to type the other side. Providing the type signature inline e.g.

```
 let choice4 : Choice<string, bool> = Choice1Of2 "test"
```

Means you are filling the hole and providing the debugger enough information to represent the type correctly.

EDIT (see comments): choice3 is represented as `Choice1Of2<string,obj>` because `obj` is considered the Top (most general type). This is the type inference mechanisms fall back type that is used when it has exhausted all other options. If we add some code e.g.

```
let result =
    match choice3 with
    | Choice1Of2 t -> t.GetHashCode()
    | Choice2Of2 t -> t
```

then we will get `Choice<string, int>` as the type of `GetHashCode()` is `int` thus the result of the second match clause must be `int` for the type of the *result* let expression to be consistent.

Comment: I don't think that's the whole explanation. The problem is that `'a` represents a "hole" as well. I suspect the answer is that the compiler is still waiting to see if it will encounter some other information that allows it to specify the type parameter more concretely, and that it has a different representation for "hole that has yet to be filled" than it does for "hole that will not be filled".

Comment: But you have already constrained 'a to string by instantiating Choice1Of2 "test". So that is no longer a hole.

Comment: I'm talking about the other `'a`, the `'a` in `Choice<string, 'a>`. But now that I've got this code up in VS, I see that `choice4` is typed the way I'd expect (`Choice<string, 'a>`), and it's `choice3` that I find a little surprising. (I'm also new to F# but I've worked with OCaml.) I'm not sure at what point it decides that the second parameter of `choice3` should be `obj`.

Comment: The type inference will always infer back to obj, if it has no other information. This is the top type. If you added `match choice3 with | Choice1Of2 t -> t.GetHashCode() | Choice2Of2 t -> t` then this will infer the type as Choice<string, int> as the type inference mechanism now has enough info.

Comment: But that still doesn't explain what exactly it is about `choice3` that makes it choose to go with the default type (`obj`) rather than leaving the second type parameter unspecified as it's doing with `choice4`. I'm guessing that it has something to do with a difference in how F# types methods vs. values.

Comment: Or, rather, what it assumes about return values of methods vs. what it assumes about return values of constructors.

Comment: @ColinBull Thank you for your input.  If I understand you correctly, the typing isn't always statically defined at compile time?  As though the compiler is checking my types for errors, but doesn't necessarily compile that information into the output?

Comment: The typing is statically defined at compile time. However the type Choice<string,'a> is still open to interpretation, because the 'a is essentially a hole. What you see in the debug window is a side effect of the debugger trying to fill this hole.